# Flutter app build in terminal size shows differ in explorer

Tags: flutter, build

Currently I am building an apk from the terminal. The build end size shows 24.9MB. But when I open in build folder in Explorer it shows 56.9MB.

Steps used:

- flutter clean
- flutter build apk

[image]

[image]

Usually, the build size in the terminal will be the same as in Explorer. But now it shows double the size in Explorer. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Flutter builds two types of APKs: debug and release. The release APK, found in build/app/outputs/flutter-apk/app-release.apk, is smaller and optimized for production. The debug APK, the one displayed in file explorers, is larger due to features like hot reload and is intended for development and testing, not distribution.

check your release apk in the

```
build/app/outputs/flutter-apk/app-release.apk
```

or you can CTRL+click on the path in terminal and it will open that path in file explorer for you.

[The app size of a debug build is large due to the debugging overhead that allows for hot reload and source-level debugging. As such, it is not representative of a production app end users download.](https://docs.flutter.dev/perf/app-size#debug-builds-are-not-representative)

Comment: I am currently in that folder. But the release.apk is not there. I tried the same process again after I once restarted the system. This time after the build it shows the release.apk the same size as in the terminal. I don't know why that happened.

Comment: if you have run the `flutter clean` command the apk will be deleted you have to run `flutter build apk` again and then when you get `Build path-to-apk` then CTRL+click on the path or go to the specified location you will find the apk there.

Answer (score 0):

For the final release you can use the following command to generate APK or appbundle for release.

Appbundle:

```
flutter build appbundle --no-tree-shake-icons --target-platform android-arm,android-arm64,android-x64 --release
```

APK:

```
flutter build apk --no-tree-shake-icons --target-platform android-arm,android-arm64,android-x64 --release
```

The size of your application release decrease when it goes live in play store.

Read documentation: https://docs.flutter.dev/perf/app-size

Comment: If it helped you please vote up and marked as correct answer.